# Second mass moment for a specific rotating object

Tags: gravity, black-holes, gravitational-waves, moment-of-inertia

The polarization amplitude for gravitational waves can be written as a function of second mass moment. For example for a propagating wave along the $z$-direction, we have

$$ h_+ = \dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{G}{c^4}(\ddot{M}_{11} - \ddot{M}_{22})\\
    h_{\times} = \dfrac{2}{r}\dfrac{G}{c^4}\ddot{M}_{12}.$$

I want to know, for a specific rotating object such as Kerr black hole or Neutron star, how we can find the $M_{ij}$.

Comment: Are you asking how the mass quadrupole moment $M_{ij}$ is defined?

Comment: @Ghoster: Yes. Actually, I want to know the components of this quantity(Its specific form as a function of time or its value) for a specific object as an example.

Answer (score 0):

The relation

[image]

which is introduced in the
https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.51.5360
described the mentioned evolution for two binary Neutron Stars. The $I_{ij}$ is the second mass moment. The other parameters are related to the mass and distances of the system.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).